# How to delete characters in textbox one by one?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I'm getting an input from the user, for example his telephone number like this:

HTML:

```
   <input id="number_input"  type="text" size="12" maxlength="19" />
```

JavaScript:

```
    var i = 0;
    var phone_number = [];
    document.getElementById('number_input').value+=digit;
    phone_number[i]= digit ;
    i = i+1;
```

And allowing the user to delete the current input like this:

```
   function delete_num ()
  {
     document.getElementById('number_input').value=' ';
     phone_number.length=0;
     return false;
  }
```

But in this case i'm deleting all input data, how can i delete the input on by one by activating delete_num function?

Thanks.

Comment: You mean like a [Backspace] button would? remove the last character from the end of the line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work just like a [Backspace] button, removing the last character from the number_input field.

```
function delete_num ()
{
    var field = document.getElementById('number_input');
    field.value = field.value.slice(0, -1); //Extract from index 0 to the before-last character
    phone_number.pop(); //Remove the last element from the phone number. It's length is maintained by js itself.
    return false; //What's this for?
}
```

Comment: Nope, the -2 is needed to get the index of the before-last character in the string.
String.length is `3` on `"abc"`. to get the index of 'b', we'd need to use String.length - 2, as the index is 1.
That said,I replaced the `.substring` with `.slice`, a function that was actually made for operations like this.
(This was in response to someone saying `String.substring(0, String.length -2)` would remove 2 characters from the end)

Comment: Nope ;) Second parameter of `substr` means length (count of symbols to take), not index. If you think that is wrong - go and explain that to my Chrome

Comment: I was using `.substring()`, not `.substr()`.

`.substring()` takes character indexes as parameters, not string length.

Comment: Hm. Than - my mistake, sorry. Anyway, you have my +1

Comment: Thanks! it works great but, if i delete a few digits and that re enter them, the string starts from the beginning and not from the index that i deleted.

Comment: Hm, I just noticed `phone_number` is an array. You can't (or at least shouldn't) edit it's .length property. The property is maintained by javascript, when you change the array's contents.
I'll make a quick change in the answer.

I'm not quite sure what you mean with "the string starts from the beginning". how are you typing in the field (Keyboard / js buttons), and what exactly are the results?

Comment: Ooo.. That did the job. Thanks you for your help! ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
function delete_num() {
  var input, num;
  input = document.getElementById('number_input');
  num = input.value;
  input.value = num.slice(0,num.length-1);
  return false;
}
```

Comment: `num = el.value;`: did you mean `num = input.value;`?

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
var input = document.getElementById('number_input');
input.value = input.value.slice(0, -1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose this is what you need:

```
function delete_num ()
  {
     var val = document.getElementById('number_input').value;
     val = val.susbtr(0,val.length - 1);
     phone_number.length = val.length;
     document.getElementById('number_input').value = val;
     return false;
  }
```

Comment: This would bring the phone_number.length below 0, if the function were to be executed, when the field's already empty.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are recreating backspace functionality...

```
function delete_num()
{
   var text = document.getElementById('number_input').value;
   document.getElementById('number_input').value = text.substring(0, text.length - 2);
   phone_number.length = 0; //not sure what this is...
   return false;
}
```

Comment: No need to assign a temporary variable, here.

Answer (score 0):

```
         function RemoveVal(events) {
           var objectControl = $find("<%= txtDescription.ClientID %>");
           var c = objectControl.get_value();
           if (c[0] == "%") {
             var shortenedString = c.substr(c[0],'');
            $find("<%= txtDescription.ClientID %>").set_value(shortenedString.toString());
           }
       }
```